# pandas multiple independent indexes(not multi index)

Tags: python, pandas

I have few large pandas `data frames` in python and would like to improve the speed of join operations by adding `index`. In the similar lines of adding index to a `database table`.

What i see when searched is only `multi-index` options. which it looks like a `composite index/multi column index` in databases.

What i need is independent indexes on few columns,(Independent because the columns are not related) so that the joins would hopefully work faster.

Is it possible to define few columns as independent index in pandas?

Comment: Why not just use `DataFrame.merge` and specify the columns? Speedwise it should be up there as well since it uses hash tables.

Comment: I already merge by specifying columns only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, As you looked, You can use multilevel index in df but if you want independent indexes on specific column, you can apply a trick by setting and resetting index as before joining operation.